# SSRS View layout different than Print layout

Tags: sql, reporting-services

In the normal view layout, my form report is formatted perfectly. When I change to Print layout, the right-most inch or two is cut off and put on a second page. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that your page size is 8.5 inches with 1 inch margins.  You'll need to fix that so the total page size including margins is 8.5".  I usually do a 7.5" page with 0.5" margins.  (To see those settings, click on the background and then look in the Properties window).